# Horizontal color lines artifacts / bug with GDAL Tiff

Tags: python, gdal, multithreading

I would like to **document a bug** I encountered, and scratched my head against several hours:

I wrote a python script for extracting (cropping) many images from a big TIF image. I used both `gdal.ReprojectImage` and `ReadASArray`.

I ended up having really strange bugs in output, like so :
[image: Imgur]

This happens my script was using multithreading (parallellization), which is wrong : gdal is not thread safe when accessing a common dataset.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: There is a note about thread safety in [GDAL's FAQ](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQMiscellaneous#IstheGDALlibrarythread-safe)